# Merge [industry-term] with [terminology]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[industry-term](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industry-term) has only 5 questions where it's used, no usage guidance or tag summary, and is equivalent to [terminology](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology).

Can we please get these tags merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've merged [industry-term](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industry-term) in to [terminology](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) and created a synonym for future use.